How to make custom splash bottles function like vanilla splash water bottle?
I'm working on an addon (MCVE demo version downloadable here) which expands brewing to include new recipes and ingredients. While the regular custom bottles and potions all function as intended, the splash versions are very buggy and have major differences from their vanilla analogs.
Unfortunately, it appears that the vanilla addon pack does not include all the files relevant to implementing custom projectiles (such as these splash-potion-type bottles). Some appear to be hardcoded instead, such as the item.json file.
Neither the official documentation for projectile items and entities, nor the Bedrock Wiki tutorial (which is also for an earlier format version), addresses these specific issues:

When thrown, the custom splash bottles immediately hit the player, unless the player is moving backwards at high speed when throwing the bottle.
The bottles will sometimes collide with air blocks before/instead of hitting the ground. This is not supposed to happen, and I wouldn't have expected it to be possible.
The event property which is supposed to point to the entity which fired the projectile (in this case, the entity which threw the splash bottle) is always undefined, instead of returning a reference to the player.
The textures of the entity versions of the splash bottles (i.e., the ones used when they are in flight, as opposed to the item texture when it is in the player's inventory or the menu screen) appears tilted into the plane of the screen, instead of viewed straight-on like the vanilla ones are.
Upon impact, the potion briefly turns red, as if it were a regular entity that has been damaged. I wouldn't expect this to happen, since the projectile entity doesn't have a "minecraft:health" component or take fall damage, but instead uses the "remove_on_hit" property of the "minecraft:projectile" component.

Does anyone have a fix for any of these issues, or have you seen a working implementation of this kind of thing which I could use as a reference?

BEHAVIOR PACK FILES:

Item .json file (BP):
{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "minecraft:item": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "splash:splash_chorus_extract_bottle_item",
            "menu_category": {
                "group": "itemGroup.name.splashPotion",
                "category": "equipment"
            }
        },

        "components": {
            "minecraft:icon": {
                "texture": "splash_chorus_extract_bottle"
            },
            "minecraft:display_name":{
                "value": "item.splash:splash_chorus_extract_bottle.name"
            },
            "minecraft:throwable": {},
            "minecraft:projectile": {
                "projectile_entity": "splash:splash_chorus_extract_bottle"
            },
            "minecraft:max_stack_size": 1,
            "minecraft:hand_equipped": true
        }
    }
}

Entity .json file (BP):
{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "minecraft:entity": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "splash:splash_chorus_extract_bottle",
            "is_spawnable": false,
            "is_summonable": true,
            "is_experimental": false
        },

        "components": {
            "minecraft:collision_box": {
                "width": 0.25,
                "height": 0.25
            },
            "minecraft:projectile": {
                "splash_potion": true,
                "on_hit": {
                    "douse_fire": { },
                    "remove_on_hit": { }
                },
                "power": 0.5,
                "gravity": 0.05,
                "angle_offset": -20.0,
                "hit_sound": "glass",
                "hit_ground_sound": "glass"
            },
            "minecraft:physics": {},
            "minecraft:pushable": {
                "is_pushable": true,
                "is_pushable_by_piston": true
            },
            "minecraft:conditional_bandwidth_optimization": {
                "default_values": {
                    "max_optimized_distance": 80.0,
                    "max_dropped_ticks": 5,
                    "use_motion_prediction_hints": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Script file (BP):
mport { world, system } from "@minecraft/server"

// Useful Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/minecraft-server?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable

// Custom splash potion effects: bottle hits a block
world.afterEvents.projectileHitBlock.subscribe(event => {
    // This often logs "air," even though splash potions shouldn't 'collide' with air blocks.
    console.warn("Block hit by bottle: " + (event.getBlockHit().block.isAir ? "air" : event.getBlockHit().block.getItemStack().typeId));
    
    // If a splash chorus extract bottle thrown by an entity hits any non-air block, teleport that entity within a random 4-block radius of the impact point
    if (!event.getBlockHit().block.isAir) {
        if (event.projectile.typeId === "splash:splash_chorus_extract_bottle") {
            // event.source is always 'undefined,' even though the documentation says it should point to the entity which fired the projectile. Expected: a "minecraft:player" instance.
            console.warn(event.source);
            if (event.source !== undefined) {
                console.warn("Custom teleport action applied to player upon splash bottle impacting ground");
            }
        }
    }
});

// Custom splash potion effects: bottle hits an entity
world.afterEvents.projectileHitEntity.subscribe(event => {
    // The bottle always hits the player immediately upon being thrown, unless the player is moving backwards at high speed when throwing it. This is not the intended or desired outcome.
    // Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/projectilehitblockafterevent?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable
    if (event.projectile.typeId === "splash:splash_chorus_extract_bottle") {
        console.warn("Custom teleport action applied to entity upon splash bottle impacting the entity");
        console.warn("Entity hit by bottle: " + event.getEntityHit().entity.typeId);
    }
});


RESOURCE PACK FILES:

Client entity file (RP):
{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "minecraft:client_entity": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "splash:splash_chorus_extract_bottle",
            "materials": {
                "default": "entity_alphatest"
            },
            "textures": {
                "default": "textures/items/splash_chorus_extract_bottle"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "default": "geometry.item_sprite"
            },
            "render_controllers": [ "controller.render.custom_splash_potion" ],
            "animations": {
                "flying": "animation.actor.billboard"
            },
            "scripts": {
                "animate": [
                    "flying"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
} 

Render controller (RP):
{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "render_controllers": {
        "controller.render.custom_splash_potion": {
            "arrays": {
                "textures": {
                    "Array.skins": [
                        "Texture.default"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "geometry": "Geometry.default",
            "materials": [ { "*": "Material.default" } ],
            "textures": [ "Array.skins[0]" ],
            "filter_lighting": true
        }
    }
}

Item texture map file:
{
    "resource_pack_name": "SplashRP",
    "texture_name": "atlas.items",
    "texture_data": {
        "splash_slime_bottle": {
            "textures": "textures/items/splash_slime_bottle"
        },
        "splash_lava_bottle": {
            "textures": "textures/items/splash_lava_bottle"
        },
        "splash_powder_snow_bottle": {
            "textures": "textures/items/splash_powder_snow_bottle"
        },
        "splash_chorus_extract_bottle": {
            "textures": "textures/items/splash_chorus_extract_bottle"
        }
    }
}


For the "bottle immediately hits the player" issue, I tried setting an "offset" value within the "minecraft:projectile" component, but that did not solve the issue or have any noticeable effect at all. Changing the "anchor" value from default (0) to 2 did not work, either.
